# ASUS Zenbook UX303LA drops WiFi connection after USB 3.0 storage or pendrive connects to USB port

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, asus-laptop, zenbook

When I connect a USB 3.0 HDD or pendrive to my new ASUS Zenbook UX303LA, it drops the WiFi connection. This does not happen for USB 2.0 devices.

I already have a wireless mouse adapter connected and it runs quite good. I am running Windows 10 x64 on this machine.

How to fix it? I believe it is a software problem.

Comment: Problem exist only if device is with USB 3.0 interface.

Comment: I have heard of similar cases with poorly shielded USB cables. Cann;t imagine much cable leading up to the pendrive though.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. The hard drive enclosure has greater power requirements, so the WiFi card loses electricity and its firmware restarts it several times and everything fails. Upgrade to the newest drivers (version 18 or higher) from the Intel's web site, and connect the hard drive on the sole USB port on the right, the one that has power for charging when the laptop is off. When WiFi drops again, you will need to shut down the laptop and boot it up again.